# SQL selecting only rows from 2nd table, containing exact results received from 1st table

Tags: sql

The answer must be rather simple, but I stuck with it for a while.
2 tables

1. BUILDING-TYPE
   Some types of work are located in some buildings
2. WORKER-TYPE
   Worker can do some types of work

| TYPE_BLD_ID | BLD | TYPE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 6 | 2 | 5 |
| 7 | 2 | 6 |
| 8 | 3 | 6 |
| 9 | 4 | 2 |
| 4 | 5 | 3 |
| 3 | 5 | 4 |
| 5 | 5 | 7 |
| 13 | 6 | 1 |
| 14 | 6 | 7 |
| 12 | 7 | 5 |

| WRK_TYPE_ID | WORKER | TYPE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 1 | 3 |
| 4 | 1 | 4 |
| 6 | 1 | 7 |
| 7 | 2 | 2 |
| 11 | 2 | 4 |
| 10 | 2 | 5 |
| 9 | 2 | 6 |
| 12 | 2 | 7 |
| 15 | 3 | 5 |
| 14 | 3 | 6 |
| 19 | 3 | 7 |
| 17 | 4 | 1 |
| 16 | 4 | 2 |
| 18 | 4 | 7 |

WHEN I select e.g. Building #4, I expect getting Worker #1, who can handle types of work 1&7.
It looks rather stupidly simple, but

1. I select types of work from the building:
   `SELECT TYPE FROM TYPES_IN_BUILDING WHERE BLD = 1;`
   Get 1 and 7
2. NEXT I do
   `SELECT WORKER FROM WORKER_TYPES WHERE TYPE IN (1,7);`

And, obviously receive all workers, who can do 1 and 7.
But I want to get ONLY WORKERS, who has BOTH types, 1 AND 7.

The issue in the question - JOINs in the SQL version, used in my system, something extremely outdated.

THE FOLLOWING WUERY DID NOT WORK:

'''

```
SELECT * FROM WORKER W
WHERE W.WORKER IN (SELECT WA.WORKER
    FROM WORKER_ATYPE WA
    WHERE WA.ATYPE IN 
    (SELECT AB.ATYPE FROM ATYPE_IN_BUILD AB WHERE AB.BLD = 6)
    GROUP BY WA.WORKER
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ATYPE) = 
        (SELECT COUNT(ATYPE) FROM TYPE_IN_BUILD WHERE BLD = 6)
 ;
```

'''

Comment: What is your DBMS? Also, build out an example of what you have and what you're trying to get in something like https://dbfiddle.uk/. Also clarify how the two tables relate to each other. Do they link on "Type"? Also, you mention Building #4, but your example data doesn't include a #4.

Comment: `select worker from worker_types where type in (1, 7) group by worker having count(distinct type) = 2`

Comment: I think you need to check what you've written, I suspect you mean building #1 not #4, and your sample data has only a single unique worker with type 1&7, I think you need more diverse sample data to clarify your requirements.

Comment: There is no building 4, so I'm really confused.

Answer (score 1):

You want the worker types to be a superset of the building types.  You can do this using:

```
select w.worker
from (select b.*, count(*) over (partition by building) as cnt
      from building b
     ) b join
     workers w
     on b.type = w.type
where b.building = 1
group by w.worker, b.cnt
having count(*) = b.cnt;
```

This matches workers to the building based on types.  Only rows that match are included.  Then, the workers are aggregated and a worker matches if the total number of rows matches the number of types for the building.